# Increase cell hight and vertically centre cell text in table within beamer class

Tags: tables, beamer

I have the following table which I am trying to increase the height of its cells. When I increase the height, texts are bottom aligned and but not centered.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results}
\centering
\begin{table}\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\cline{1-7}
Volatility Indicator & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Returns}\\  \cline{2-7}
& Market & Manuf. & Const. & Ret. & Serv. & Finan. \\ 
\cline{1-7}
Market & 0.02{**} &  &  &  &  & 0.08{*} \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.13 &  &  &  &  & 0.10{*}\\
Manufacturing & 0.00{***} & 0.01{***} &  &  &  & 0.05{**} \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.01{***} & 0.04{**} &  &  &  & 0.04{**} \\
Construction & 0.55 &  & 0.07{*} &  &  & 0.28 \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.32 &  & 0.10{*} &  &  & 0.60 \\
Retail Trade & 0.88 &  &  & 0.16 &  & 0.70 \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.01{***} &  &  & 0.01{***} &  & 0.01{***} \\
Services & 0.10{*} &  &  &  & 0.09{*} & 0.18 \\
(r g-cause vol)& 0.00{***} &  &  &  & 0.1{*} & 0.01{***} \\
Services [WT] & 0.46 &  &  &  & 0.12 & 0.81\\
(r g-cause vol)[WT] & 0.00{***} &  &  &  & 0.03{**} & 0.02{**} \\
\cline{1-7}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to increase the height? Does `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` work?

Comment: @samcarter This was there before moving the table from an article class to beamer but I removed it as I wanted to downscale the table to fit the slide. tried it again now and worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` will influence the cell height of your table.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results}
\centering
\begin{table}\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\cline{1-7}
Volatility Indicator & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Returns}\\  \cline{2-7}
& Market & Manuf. & Const. & Ret. & Serv. & Finan. \\ 
\cline{1-7}
Market & 0.02{**} &  &  &  &  & 0.08{*} \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.13 &  &  &  &  & 0.10{*}\\
Manufacturing & 0.00{***} & 0.01{***} &  &  &  & 0.05{**} \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.01{***} & 0.04{**} &  &  &  & 0.04{**} \\
Construction & 0.55 &  & 0.07{*} &  &  & 0.28 \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.32 &  & 0.10{*} &  &  & 0.60 \\
Retail Trade & 0.88 &  &  & 0.16 &  & 0.70 \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.01{***} &  &  & 0.01{***} &  & 0.01{***} \\
Services & 0.10{*} &  &  &  & 0.09{*} & 0.18 \\
(r g-cause vol)& 0.00{***} &  &  &  & 0.1{*} & 0.01{***} \\
Services [WT] & 0.46 &  &  &  & 0.12 & 0.81\\
(r g-cause vol)[WT] & 0.00{***} &  &  &  & 0.03{**} & 0.02{**} \\
\cline{1-7}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `booktabs`, and `cellspace` to get some vertical padding of cells symmetrically at the top and bottom of cells.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results}
\centering
\begin{table}\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{Sl}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}[-\aboverulesep]{Volatility Indicator} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Returns}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-7}%
& Market & Manuf. & Const. & Ret. & Serv. & Finan. \\
\midrule%\cline{1-7}
Market & 0.02{**} & & & & & 0.08{*} \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.13 & & & & & 0.10{*}\\
Manufacturing & 0.00{***} & 0.01{***} & & & & 0.05{**} \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.01{***} & 0.04{**} & & & & 0.04{**} \\
Construction & 0.55 & & 0.07{*} & & & 0.28 \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.32 & & 0.10{*} & & & 0.60 \\
Retail Trade & 0.88 & & & 0.16 & & 0.70 \\
(r g-cause vol) & 0.01{***} & & & 0.01{***} & & 0.01{***} \\
Services & 0.10{*} & & & & 0.09{*} & 0.18 \\
(r g-cause vol)& 0.00{***} & & & & 0.1{*} & 0.01{***} \\
Services [WT] & 0.46 & & & & 0.12 & 0.81\\
(r g-cause vol)[WT] & 0.00{***} & & & & 0.03{**} & 0.02{**} \\
\bottomrule%
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}[
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uicc.png)